# External libraries are not found in the final build

Tags: java, gradle, dependencies, build.gradle

I been working on a project that uses an external  jar file. Whenever, I build my project using build.grade, and the external files does not get added to the final jar file. Inside my workspace, I have a "libs" folder which holds the external jar file (Discord Rich Presence). Can anyone help me sort this out?

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            name = "forge"
            url = "http://files.minecraftforge.net/maven"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'net.minecraftforge.gradle:ForgeGradle:2.1-SNAPSHOT'
        
    }
}
apply plugin: 'net.minecraftforge.gradle.forge'

version = "1.0"
group= "com.yourname.modid"
archivesBaseName = "example"

minecraft {
    version = "1.8.9-11.15.1.1722"
    runDir = "run"
    
    mappings = "stable_20"
}

repositories {
    flatDir {
    dirs "libs"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile name: 'discord-rpc'
}

processResources {
    inputs.property "version", project.version
    inputs.property "mcversion", project.minecraft.version

    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        include 'mcmod.info'
                
        expand 'version':project.version, 'mcversion':project.minecraft.version
    }
        
    from(sourceSets.main.resources.srcDirs) {
        exclude 'mcmod.info'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The default task `jar` only packages the files of project source code. To include all the dependencies inside the JAR file, you could try https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/com.github.johnrengelman.shadow:

```gradle
plugins {
    ...
    id "com.github.johnrengelman.shadow" version "7.0.0"
}

...
```

Run this command to package all:

```
$ ./gradlew shadowJar
```